# Looking for GPS device with on-board RTK that is easy to interface to from an iOS App

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, gps

I've been researching a possible iOS-based app, developed in Unity, that would require a high-degree of positional accuracy (centimeters).

I expect I would need to connect, from the app, to an external GPS device using Bluetooth (or similar) and obtain NMEA sentences (or similar) containing location data.

My research has brought me to RTK, which is extremely accurate. From what I've seen already, it seems that normally GPS receivers which offer this operate themselves at normal GPS precision (2-2.5m). The correction to a high-accuracy location happens in software on a connected computer or tablet with a connection to an NTRIP server.

Assuming what I've said is correct, does anyone know of a GPS device that performs this RTK correction on the GPS device itself? Ideally I could just connect with Bluetooth or similar and get NMEA (or equivalent) data with high-accuracy location.

It may also be that I'm thinking about this incorrectly. On iOS, assuming there is an 3rd party app performing the RTK calculations, is there a standard way to obtain that high-accuracy location? Alternatively, are there GPS vendors that supply SDKs that would allow me to get to where I need to go?

Thanks very much,

Kieran

Answer (score 3):

There is a recent module from U-Blox named [ZED-F9P](https://rtklibexplorer.wordpress.com/2018/11/30/a-first-look-at-the-u-blox-zed-f9p-dual-frequency-receiver/) which has internal processing and is faster then RTKLib. Check [this blog](https://rtklibexplorer.wordpress.com/2018/11/30/a-first-look-at-the-u-blox-zed-f9p-dual-frequency-receiver/)  for performance

You can buy a board like ArduSimple's [simpleRTK2B](https://www.ardusimple.com/simplertk2b/) with an XBee module for WiFi/Blutooth or something similar from Sparkfun. You could also wait for the development board from U-Blox which is not yet available.